# UILabel not displaying in detail view

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am learning Swift at the moment, trying to build a simple table view controller and a detail view which displays the passed data by the master (table view controller) via segue. Not sure what I am doing wrong but I cant see my label on the detail view (I am testing this on a simulator at the moment). I have tried printing it to the console and I can see the text property of the label is set.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

**Detail view controller**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    detailItem = ["title": "YES"]
    if let title: String = self.detailItem["title"] {
        if let label = self.titleLabel {
            label.text = title as String?
            println(title)
            println(label)
        }
    }
}
```

**Console output**

```
YES
<UILabel: 0x7fc731e2f220; frame = (0 -21; 42 21); text = 'YES'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc731e05ee0>>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see the label with default value

Comment: are you sure you can see you label?

Comment: Your label is 21 points wide and has an offset of -21 points. It's offscreen probably. Have you set it up with Autolayout?

Comment: No i cant see the label with default value. Nothing shows up. Just white screen. Also tried adding a button just to test it and doesnt work

Comment: use constraints and set width and height

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Comment: Yes i did set it up with auto layout. Got all the constraints sorted and no auto layout issues

Comment: Did you set height and width??

Comment: Yes height: 28 width: 368

Comment: Can you show us the AutoLayout constraints? They're displayed on the Size Inspector. (ps: in my previous comment I said 'wide', but meant 'high')

Comment: Maybe some screenshot?

Comment: yes...Show me a  screenshot

Comment: Is there anything obvious from the screenshot? Anyway I look into see why the label frame is out of bounds

Comment: are you sure this is the same label as the one connected to titleLabel? Where is it located in the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Set width and height]

check my screenshot and set width and height

Answer (score 0):

```
labeloutlet.text = stringvar // i thing this will work
```

Comment: if you are not able to see the label with default value. Check the constraints u have applied.

Answer (score 0):

Label was out of bounds. I found the label on an ipad landscape mode hiding on the left side. Time to RTFM thoroughly. Thanks for the help guys